# О выражении «на скаку»

Tags: этимология, фразеология

От какого слова это выражение, не пойму? Ведь нету же слова "скак".

Comment: скак-скок-скоч, скакать, скачок, скачущий, скак+нуть~прыг+нуть~прибегнуть, на скаку~на бегу, скакать - на скаку, бежать - на бегу, лететь - на лету. Слова не образуются от слов(редко), слова образуются от корня слова и словообразующих элементов по похожести с уже существующим словом. Почему нет формы скак или скоч - без окончания? потому что это разовое действие. Нет слова прыг? но есть, как-то: а он прыг на ветку, а он скок на печку/скок-поскок, молодой дроздок. Так что есть скок.

Comment: Во чаго нашол: "К этой форме мгновенно-прошедшего относятся слова: глядь, хвать, прыг, щелк, стук, бряк, звяк, бух, шлеп, скок, миг, шмыг, бац, кех, плюх, пих и пр." И. В. Киреевский. Письмо К. С. Аксакову (1855)

Comment: Бегать – бег, скакать – скак. Обычное усечение основы.

Comment: Было: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/скак

Comment: Классно!)))))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В словарях на "Грамоте":
орфографический — [скак: на скаку, на всём (на полном) скаку](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA);
БТС — <СКАК>. На (всём, полном и т. п.) скаку. ***В зн. нареч.*** Во время движения вскачь. *Обернуться на скаку. На всём скаку врезался в гущу толпы. На полном скаку выстрелил по летящей птице.*

А словечко-то есть!
В словаре русских народных говоров (вып. 37, [стр. 367–368](https://nenadict.iling.spb.ru/publications/1363)):
**Скак**, м. Во весь скак. Очень быстро; стремительно, во весь опор. *Казак скачет во весь скак, лошадь-то как пыхнула — и давай его таскать и затаскала до смерти.* Р. Урал, 1976.
**Ска́ка**, ж. Быстрая езда на лошади, скачка. *Казаки всегда на конях верхам служили, и вот в особенности во время схватки с врагом тут така скака во всю силу. Вот это скаки-драки.* Р. Урал, 1976.

У Лопатина в ПАС ([Особенности написания отдельных корней](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=6272)):

> **скак — скок — скач — скоч.** Если корень оканчивается на ***к***, то на месте безударного гласного пишется буква ***а***, напр.: *скака́ть, прискака́ть, ускака́ть, скакну́ть, скака́лка, скаку́н, на скаку́, скаково́й*, хотя под ударением — ***о***, напр.: *ско́к, наско́к, отско́к, поско́к, соско́к*...

В Нацкорпусе:
*Сказав печальное прости храбрым сослуживцам, золотому мундиру и вороному коню, села я на перекладную телегу и понеслась **во весь скак** по дороге к Пинску* (Н. А. Дурова. Кавалерист-девица (1835)).

Comment: Спасибо большое, Рим! Круто, что есть и "скак" и "скака"! :) Прости, что на восклицательный знак поменял, но очень хотелось, надеюсь, ты не против.

Comment: Восклицательный знак — "наикрутейшейший", к месту! Как же я могу быть против? Спасибо за вопрос, Артём! Слово "скак" есть в моей памяти (дед, родом откуда-то из Сибири (1912), говорил: *скак да поскак, а толку никак*). А вот "ска́ка" — сущая "удивлительность" (это, кстати, тоже его словцо).

Comment: Очень интересно!!!

Comment: Поклон-поклонище еще раз! Некоторые слова и выражения (его и бабушкины) я часто использую в своем лексиконе, даже не задумываясь...

Comment: И правильно делаешь! Я тоже употребляю выражения и слова дедушки с бабушкой.

Answer (score 1):

> "К этой форме мгновенно-прошедшего относятся слова: глядь, хвать,
> прыг, щелк, стук, бряк, звяк, бух, шлеп, скок, миг, шмыг, бац, кех,
> плюх, пих и пр." И. В. Киреевский. Письмо К. С. Аксакову (1855)

Скак-скок-скач-скоч. Хотя я бы урезал основу корня до кач-коч: кочевник, качать, кочка, качка, кач-кач - произносят, когда качают малыша на качелях. Скачок - более экспрессивное действие связанное с подскакиванием - подпрыгиванием и отрывом от того, на чем качаются. То есть скак = кач+прыг, двунаправленное действие, с качанием и из стороны в сторону(тем, что качается) и с подпрыгиванием(над тем, что качает), хотя корень явно от КАЧ. Забавно, что слово КАЧ отсутствует у Киреевского.

А еще я нашел [такое](https://anti-fasmer.livejournal.com/259288.html):

> 走る [hashiru; хассирю] (яп.) - бежать;

> [kaš] (шумер.) – быстро бежать;

> качыр- (ойрот. алтайск.), қашыр- (каз.) – гнать, прогнать; обращать в бегство;

> качу (тат.), кач- (ойрот. алтайск.), қаш- (каз.), kaç(mak) [кач(мак)] (тур.), qaç(maq) [кач(мак)] (азер.) – бежать, мчаться; убегать, обращаться в бегство, сбежать; удирать, удрать; скрываться, скрыться, перен. дезертировать / уклоняться от работы; kaçak [качак] (тур.), качак (тат.), қашақ (каз.) – беглый, беглец, бежавший;

> Ср. казаки – «беглый, свободный люд» (по Карамзину);

> koş(mak) [кош(мак)] (тур.) – бежать, мчаться, скакать, спешить, торопиться;

> koşu [кощю] (тур.) – бег, состязание в беге, пробег; скачки; koşucu [кощюджю] (тур.) – участник состязания в бегах, бегун;

> caccia [качча] (ит.) – охота (прежде всего верховая); cacciare [каччаре] (ит.), caçar [качар] (порт.), cazar [касар] (исп.), kaċċa (мальт.), chacier (арх. фр.),

> chasse [шасс] (фр.), chase [чейс] (англ.) – гнаться за кем.-л., преследовать;

> [khácati] (санскр., по Фасмеру) - выпрыгивает;

> šokti (лит.) - прыгать, подпрыгивать; танцевать.
>
> Ср. также с: hız [хыз] (тур.) - «скорость, спешка» haste [хэйст]
> (англ.) – торопиться, спешить; häst [хæст] (шв.), hest [хест] (дат.,
> норв.) - лошадь.

добавочка:

> haste [хэйст] (англ.) – торопиться, спешить; häst [хæст] (шв.), hest
> [хест] (дат., норв.) - лошадь.
>
> Это ингушское касст: вскоре, скоро, Кастта: скорее Чеченский язык
> вскоре(kеstta): кестта

То есть если верить тому же Фасмеру, то праславянское  *kotiti, *koti̯ǫ связано(хотя напрямую у него это не указано, но очевидно) с праиндоевропейским [khácati] (санскр., по Фасмеру) - выпрыгивает. С придыханием, так понимаю, звук между к и х. И в каких-то случаях - это может быть качаться-подпрыгивать-выпрыгивать, а в каких-то быстро перемещаться(на лошади) - скакать, сравнимо с бежать - ускакать-убежать. Но тут наверное сказываются особенности быстрого перемещения - на лошади быстрее, чем ногами, поэтому все ровные пацаны перемещались не на своих двоих.

Ну и западные корни лошадь - horse (скакун), спешка - haste (скачка), и даже новомодное skate (кататься, ср. скотина) - скорее всего связаны c корнями КОТИТИ - КХАЧИТИ. Ну и всякие чеченские слова вроде кататься на машине(по аналогии на лошади) будут  - ХАХКА МАШЕН - гнать, кататься на машине.

Как видите, корни слов и языки гораздо более связанные, с точки зрения этимологии и неспособность вычленить корень и всякая семантика, усложняет понимание языковой картины мира.

И я бы даже согласился с Фасмером, если бы не было шумерского [kaš] (шумер.) – быстро бежать. Так что корень КАЧ, а его производные - качать, катиться, кочка, качели, скакун, скачок, скакать и даже казак, ну и всякие старославянские  скачѫ.

И вообще я поражён популярностью этого корня и ареалом его распространения, причем в русском языке он максимально приближен к оригиналу и содержит множество связанных с ним слов не противоречащих первооснове, кроме разве что сленговых: качок, качать железо(педивикия) и производных переносных качать насосом воду (Даль) - тут тоже ошибка, потому что тут качать(совершать колебательные движения, которые скорее всего производная от качании на лошади, но тем не менее) однако, не воду качают, а качают насосом воду, качают относится к насос и движению насосом, а не качанию воды, ну или это быстро налить воду - накачать...

То есть КАЧ - это изначально, указание на быстрое перемещение, но связанное с КАЧКОЙ на лошади - функционально СКАКУНЕ, отсюда все производные смыслы КАЧАТЬ - подпрыгивать, колеблясь из стороны в сторону.

Жаргонизмы же вроде КАЧОК - это не тот, кого накачали, а тот кто быстро раскачался - получил мышцы, СКАЧИВАТЬ - получать информацию, также тяготеет по смыслу к быстро.

Ну и к быстроте можно вспомнить дореволюционное: катись колбаской по малой Спасской, - то есть, быстро и далеко уходи отсюда, убегай.

А кот-кошка - быстро выпрыгивающее животное. Сравнить: казак-кошак.

**КАЧ - быстро перемещаться > убегать/выпрыгивать > по средствам чего-то - на лошади(уже машине), а не ногами > далеко/выпуклость > совершать колебательные движения - то медленно, то быстро > накачать/накачанный~надутый - как результат быстрого~объемного формирования чего-либо.**